# What’s one word that means “worth visualizing” or “worthy of visualization”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’d like to find a way to explain in just one single word (it can be a neologism) that something will be so awesomely good-looking that it’s “worth visualizing”, that it is “worthy of visualization”.

This single word should be built around the word *visualization*.

Comment: Can you clarify what you would be "visualizing"? By visualization are you thinking of an infographic or something like that?

Comment: To be honest, what i want is a wordplay - I work in a team named "Visualization" in TomTom company, and we do some great looking things - like buildings in 3D, city landmarks and so on. Among them there is one, that is the most complex and awesome. So we want to present it to our company collegues. So that's why im searching for something like "the most Visualization-worth product of visualization team"

Comment: Could the term contain related words like 'sight' or 'mind' ?

Comment: Yes, the more proposals, the better. But I hope we can find a word that will be as close as possible to "visualization"

Comment: The problem here is that *visualization* is already a cumbersome derived word with a bunch of endings piled on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjective *[eye-popping](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eye-popping)* may be relevant; it means “Visually astonishing, stunning, incredible”.

A [google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=eye-worthy) suggests the term *eyeworthy* (also *eye worthy*, *eye-worthy*) has some currency, but so far isn't dictionary-worthy. Also consider *visualization-worthy*, a natural combination of words that isn't neologistic.

Noun *[eye candy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eye_candy#Noun)* refers to “Any object or sight with considerable visual appeal”.

For a neologism, consider *visvalization*; though clumsy at first, it reads well after acquaintance.

Comment: I think nothing but *visualization-worthy* matches his fastidious criteria. However, I also find *visualization-worthy* to be the most cringeworthily flinchable double-barrelled victim of logorrhœic planteration to spew forth from the gavaged vomitoria of the Sesquipedalariarium Royale in recent and perhaps even racial memory.

Comment: @tchrist, Although I disagree that *visualization-worthy* is the *most* cringeworthily flinchable etc. (on the grounds that far worse things are easily found), I agree  it's abhorrent and intended to say so in the answer but forgot.

Comment: Not your fault, and I’m sorry if I made it sound as though it were. The OP’s stated requirement of somehow involving *visualization* in the one-word answer is what hamstrings this. It is too narrow. I don’t know if there exists *any* word that means “worthy of X” that isn’t of the form *X-worthy*.

Answer (score 0):

[Visualize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/visualize) means:

> - *To form a mental image of*; envisage: tried to visualize the scene as it was described.

I suggest a related term : [mind-catching](http://www.mindcatching.com/blog/what_is_mind_catching_design/)

> - Mind-catching design is more like a motto to me. That is, design is more than eye-catching; it’s about mind-catching. While eye-catching implies beauty, mind-catching means beauty + memorable and powerful content in a complete package. While eye-catching may lean toward creativity in general, mind-catching is more about strategic creativity.

also:

[Mind -boggling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mind-boggling)

> - adj. Informal
>     Intellectually or emotionally overwhelming: "a mind-boggling bazaar of competing manufacturers and overlapping technologies" (William D. Marbach).
>     mind-boggler n.

Source:http://www.mindcatching.com/blog/what_is_mind_catching_design/